# Change the data in cassandra from a javascript or jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cassandra

I am using a cassandra database which has data. I want to change the data from my application which uses javascript. Is it possible to update the database with changed data using javascript?

Comment: Should be the same as updating a MySQL database. Post data to the server, then update the db.

Comment: Javascript can call server-side code to modify the database.  It cannot modify it directly, and nor should it or I'd be able to modify your database from the browser console.

Comment: But there is no update query in cassandra to do the same as MYSQL database - @JasonP

Comment: @Archer : Can u give me a demo code please

Comment: @Vidya Show us your existing form and script.  Stack Overflow is for helping you fix problems, not for writing your code.

Comment: @Archer Sir I know but mine is huge code I need this concept to be used in my code and I am stuck. So i asked for help.

Comment: @Vidya then you need Google my friend.  Good luck :)

Comment: @Vidya So your question doesn't really have anything to do with javascript, but instead how to write an `update` query with cassandra? Maybe see [this link](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#updateStmt)?

Answer (score 0):

just if your server side is writed using some javacript framework like NodeJS . if its just a html with javacript there is no way to update the database form there you have to past data to server side first. If you could change data directly from javacript every person that visit your site can do the same!